# "404 - file or directory not found" in jquery datatable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have two sites configured in remote server, Production and Testing.
I am facing very strange issue. One of the filter method is working properly on Production site, but on testing site it create issue "404 - file or directory not found" when i try to access that filter method. I am using this method in jquery datatable ajax method.
How can i handle this issue?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code (can you post it?), but probably the endpoint where the filtered data is loaded from does not exist on the test machine. Check the URL from which the data is loaded.

Comment: Front-end code:
 "ajax": {               
                "url": BindUrl("GetListByFilter"),
                "type": "GET"
            },

Back-end code:
 public ActionResult GetListByFilter(int? draw, int? start, ...  )
        {
....
  return Json(object, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}